# Java. Разбить программу по файлам, сделать один запускающий метод

Tags: java

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Доброго времени суток, знатоки!
Нужна помощь, я не шарю как это сделать (((

```
1. Предыдущие 3 лабораторные работы (№1, 2, 3) разбить по файлам.
```

Каждый класс должен находиться в отдельном файле. 
Каждая лабораторная работа должна находиться в отдельном пакете.
    Общий метод main должен вызывать все тесты.

Comment: Вставьте код текстом в вопрос, а не картинкой, никто перепечатывать с картинки  не будет. Для редактирования вопроса нажмите кнопку "править" внизу под вопросом.

Comment: >>я не шарю как это сделать<< ник у вас как то не вяжется...

Comment: Вообще, вопрос очень специфичный. Почему именно Stackoverflow? Почему не сообщество админов, каких нибудь, или суперюзеров? Просто, обычно, программисты заправляют кондиционеры, чинят банкоматы, а тут распилить текст на файлики. В общем, лично мне сложно вашу задачу к программированию отнести

Comment: Сейчас бы к нику прицепиться.....

Тут код не важен, по сути есть 3 правильно работающих программы (лабы), это как 3 разных микро программы, каждая в своем пакете


И мне не особо понятно задание:
 "каждый класс должен находиться в отдельном файле",
 и 
"общий метод main должен вызывать все тесты"

И поэтому спрашиваю, тк не знаю наверняка, что делать

Comment: Вроде на скрине так и сделано. Что конкретно непонятно?

Answer (score 1):

Исходя из формулировки вопроса тут все очевидно: классы и так обычно отдельными файлами создаются (если у вас там нет вложенных классов). А с чтобы все запускалось из одного main() нужно (о чудо!) создать один MainClass для всех лабораторных и тестов. А если нужен более конкретный ответ, то и вопрос должен содержать конкретный код.